# Nginx only or Nginx(reverse proxy) + Apache

Tags: apache, nginx, cpanel, vps

I just rent a VPS, and I want to install nginx as a server, however, most of the article on the internet is use nginx as a reverse proxy, rather than as a server, what benefit with this configuration?

Is it possible to use 2 nginx (1 as reverse proxy another as server)?

another non-related this topic question, I'm now using cpanel, how can I fully stop apache, because the httpd is always restart after sometimes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you going to do with your Nginx? If you just want a web server you can go with only Nginx, that's fine.

Comment: I wrote a facebook application, and will put on that server, in my home's PC, I use Nginx only (only test for myself), but in VPS, I don't know what will happen when a lot of people use, I want stable and good performance environment, so I don't know how to choose.

Comment: @face: It sounds that you don't need anything more than Nginx.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I finally decide to install nginx only on the VPS, however, it seems the cpanel is one of the guy who block the road, first, I want to install mysql 5.5, however, because cpanel not support, then I give this up, then I want to remove apache, but with no luck, then I disable it, and when I try to configure php-fpm, I don't even know where is the php installed...seems it is noway to use nginx standalone rather than nginx as a reverse proxy.

Comment: @face: I installed Nginx and PHP on an Ubuntu VPS, see: [How to set up PHP with Nginx, APC and PostgreSQL?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9357/how-to-set-up-php-with-nginx-apc-and-postgresql)

Comment: @Jonas, Thanks for your post, I also ask the CS of my VPS provider, they say nginx is poor in serving dynamic page, so they don't recommend, what is your opinion?

Comment: @face: You can read http://blog.marc-seeger.de/assets/papers/alternative_infrastructure.pdf - the conclusion is that Nginx is good if you have limited hardware resoursed E.g. on a VPS.

Comment: Thanks, you give me some hints on my direction. Actually, I found that I'm start with a wrong direction, I shouldn't chosen cpanel because I use this VPS as a single site. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

Nginx works great by itself and will likely be much faster than Apache.  It also uses far less resources (RAM, CPU).  That being said, Apache brings some goods to the table, namely simplified deployment for some scenarios (and 2.4 has compelling caching features).

Nginx vs Apache is a false dichotomy. Nginx makes Apache better.  By all means, put Nginx out front, but don't write off Apache entirely if it suits your needs.